# version of PostgreSQL/PostGIS supported by Embedded Cadcorp SIS 8.0

Tags: postgis, cadcorp-sis

Can anyone tell me where I can find out what versions of PostgreSQL/PostGIS are supported by embedded Cadcorp 8.0 which I believe is based on Cadcorp SIS Map Modeller 8.0.

Answer (score 2):

Cadcorp SIS 8.0 is most recently tested with PostgreSQL 9.3.4 and PostGIS 2.13.
These are therefore recommended, but it will run with any PostgreSQL 9 and PostGIS 2 combination.

If you need to use an earlier version, then PostgreSQL 8.4 and PostGIS 1.4 with corresponding PostGIS WKT Raster are also supported.